# The Gaming logo doesn't show up on the hotdog-stand flair, can it be given an outline?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flair

It's just about visible, but only just:

[image: Bad flair]

How about:

[image: Good flair]

Comment: Irrelevant but I think the colors in your profile picture are a great match to the overall hotdog appearance.

Comment: @Mana Primary colours ftw

Comment: [status-declined] - The requested outline was never applied, and the [logo was replaced a year later anyway](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4821/28182)

Comment: @Robotnik This is a stone cold tragedy.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how it would look on the normal flair and in Firefox:

[image: Default Themed Flair]

[image: in FF]

Personally, I think this is kind of unnecessary. I can still see the heart on the hot dog stand flair. It might be a little hard on your eyes, but so is the hot dog stand flair.

Comment: I think it actually looks better with the outline elsewhere, as well.  That said I 100% agree with you that having the hot dog stand be hard on your eyes is entirely the point.

Comment: Does it have to change everywhere? Can it not just change for hot-dog-stand? I do like the white outline actually, as per [the sticker](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JxbFN.png).