# Why is the domain "gaming.stackexchange" and not arqade.stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, domain-name, stack-exchange

In every stack exchange site the domain name reflects the name of the site:

```
magento.stackexchange.com => Magento
webdev.stackexchange.com  => Web Development
```

Why does Arqade differ from this? Why is it `gaming.stackexchange` and not `arqade.stackexchange`?

Comment: There's quite a bit of history behind this. If you dig far enough into this site's meta you'll probably find it yourself

Comment: Related: [Add a redirect from arqade.stackexchange.com to gaming.stackexchange.com](//meta.arqade.com/q/11264/101016)

Comment: Also Related: [Why doesn't Arqade use it's named URL when other sites like AskUbuntu do?](//meta.arqade.com/q/15601/28182)

Answer (score 21):

The domain name of stack exchange sites reflects the topic of the site. Most sites are named after their topic and so the name and domain are the same.

This site is one of the few exceptions, where a special name was chosen, that isn't just the topic. So the domain is gaming.stackexchange.com, bacause it's a site about gaming, even though it has been named "Arqade". You can also reach the site through [arqade.com](http://arqade.com).

Another example for this would be [cooking.stackexchange.com](http://cooking.stackexchange.com), which is called "Seasoned Advice".

Comment: Also 'Ask Different' - [apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Personal Finance & money is just https://money.stackexchange.com/

Comment: And the name of [stats.stackexchange.com](http://stats.stackexchange.com) (statistics, probability and data science) is Cross Validated.

Comment: [Similar question on electronics.SE ("Electrical Engineering")](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5225/why-is-there-a-variation-in-the-stackexchange-site-name-between-url-and-title), which has had [more than its share of naming confusion](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/601).

Answer (score 7):

Gaming was the original name of the site, which is why we got the url gaming.stackexchange.com. The site eventually started pulling in a lot of traffic, but both SE and the community felt that the URL and branding of the site made it difficulty to promote. So, in order to make the site easier to promote, we were given a new name, domain (arqade.com), and branding. You can find a lot of the history [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4821/introducing-arqade) and [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4237/a-new-name-for-gaming-stack-exchange).

Answer (score 2):

The reason is actually pretty simple, the original name of this site was "Gaming beta", so naturally its URL was `gaming.stackexchange.com`. It was only when the site [got sufficiently popular](http://arqade.com) did it get its less generic, more clever (Ar**QA**de, get it?) [name](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4821/introducing-arqade).  The URL remained the same as there really wasn't much point in changing it.

I should note while there is no `arqade.stackexchange.com`. there is redirect from [arqade.com](http://arqade.com) to this site (similarly there's also one for [seasonedadvice.com](http://seasonedadvice.com)), but I'm guessing that it only exists so its not taken by squatters or some site hosting malware.

Comment: -1 This is wrong. The site came out of beta long before the name happened. The name, branding, and domain were all created to help promote the site. [More information here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4237/a-new-name-for-gaming-stack-exchange).

Comment: @Wipqozn I've corrected my post accordingly.