# Dark flair looks bad

Tags: bug, design, flair

Our new branding has fixed [previous problems with flair](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2627/3610), but has introduced a new one: The logo just looks bad on the dark flair, you can't make it out at all.

[image]

Comment: +1, was just going to post this myself.